# Powershell array .contains method doesn't seem to work as advertised

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

```
PS C:\TEMP> cat list.csv
132
456
789

PS C:\TEMP> $arrayfromcsv = Import-CSV -header Values -path "c:\TEMP\list.csv"

PS C:\TEMP> $arrayfromcsv.Length
3

PS C:\TEMP> $arrayfromcsv[2]
Values
------
789

PS C:\TEMP> $arrayfromcsv.Contains("789")
False
```

Please tell me what is going wrong here... I suspect I missed something obvious, betraying my lack of familiarity with Powershell...

Comment: I now understand how I erred: because my CSV had only one column, I did not realize that "Contains" needed to apply on a specific column and thus I needed a column selector.

Comment: To clarify on your last comment, the `Contains` method works on an array of values, however, what results of `ConvertFrom-Csv` / `Import-Csv` is actually an array of objects (no matter how many columns it has). See [`IList.Contains(Object)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.contains?view=net-6.0#system-collections-ilist-contains(system-object)) for more info :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is using `.Contains` over the object array (`$arrayfromcsv` instead of *expanding the values of each object*: `$arrayfromcsv.Values`).

You can use [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) to access all **property Values** of each object of `$arrayfromcsv`:

```sh
@'
132
456
789
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Values | Set-Variable csv

$csv.Values.Contains('789') # => True
```

Comment: Yup agreed @zett42 thanks to Mathias and mklement0 ;)

Comment: Nice, though why bring `Set-Variable` out of quasi retirement? :) @zett42: Indeed, and it is well-written too.

Comment: @mklement0 lol I don't know why I got to the habit of using `sv` probably due to the fact that I always forgot to do the variable assignment before the here-string :p

Comment: Thanks for getting the ball rolling on it, @MathiasR.Jessen.

Comment: Thank you. Though it took me a while to realize that "Values" is the column header - not a Powershell reserved word that gets values !

Comment: happy to help @Jean-MarcLiotier (re `Values` I should've clarified on that, I just assumed it was clear since you chose it as header name for your Csv) my bad :)

Comment: Serves me well for naming a column, even an example one, with such a generic name !